# reCaptcha has blocked me out of my website

Tags: users, captcha

I had enabled reCaptcha yesterday on my site. The keys that I had entered were generated for my real site while I had been working using my temp.

My site displayed this message continuously:

> Input error: Invalid referer

I didn't take it seriously for I thought it will be resolved when I start using the real url for my site.

Today, when I logged out, I realized that I was wrong. I am not able to log inside my administrator account because the captcha is blocking me out. This is the message that I got when I tried to enter the site using my login id password:

> The answer you entered for the CAPTCHA was not correct.

I can not disable the captcha on login screen because I am not able to enter the site. Should I delete the captcha module from my directory right way? Or will that screw up things further because I won't be able to clear the cache of my website?

Comment: Can you use shell?

Comment: haven't used it ever. But will be willing to try my hands on anything to enter my site right now..

Comment: Well, try to use ssh client, ie [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) ([direct link to download](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty.exe)) with your ftp/sftp credentials. If your site admin allows it, you are good and I can answer you.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. Thankfully didn't have to do any of those things. I was still using the regular drupal method to change password and hence could enter the site to change my password by placing a 'new password' request. No form was enabled yet to set the password so captcha didn't block it. Have disabled captcha for the time being now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**If you can use SSH, or other shell,** it's easy:

1. Install Drush. On Ubuntu, [follow this document](https://drupal.org/node/1248790). Or simply unpack it and add it's directory to system's PATH variable (OS dependant).
2. Enter your Drupal's directory
3. Execute `drush dis recaptcha`

I strongly advise this approach, it may be a bit hard to set up initially, but drush is a powerful tool that can help you in future.

**If you cannot, but you can use SQL client,** it's not so bad too:

1. Login to your Drupal database with your SQL client
2. Back up your entire database
3. Execute `UPDATE system SET status = 0 WHERE name = "recaptcha";`

In both cases, you should be able to login, and uninstall reCaptcha module via UI to get rid of messed configuration data.

Comment: @user18593  second option is easy to achieve, but before take backup of your DB

Comment: @Bala updated my answer. My mistake - for me hitting "backup" before things like this is a habit I don't need to think about anymore.

Comment: Also to install drush you must have the rights to do so or it maybe already installed on some hosts. But Drush will make your live easier. Using `drush uli` from the cli you get a one time login link for the admin back.

Comment: @FLY - to install drush as an user's script one does not need any special rights, just unpack it and edit `.bashrc`